# How do I fix this cmake file? c file is ignoring h file it is dependent on

Tags: c, cmake

the cmake file

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.6)
    project(producer)
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -Wall -g -pthread")

add_executable(server wrappers.h wrappers.c server.c request.h request.c)
```

the error message

```
`CMakeFiles/server.dir/wrappers.c.o: In function Pthread_create':
    /home/user/ClionProjects/producer/wrappers.c:570: undefined reference to `pthread_create'
    CMakeFiles/server.dir/wrappers.c.o: In function `Pthread_join':
    /home/user/ClionProjects/producer/wrappers.c:645: undefined reference to `pthread_join'
    CMakeFiles/server.dir/wrappers.c.o: In function `Pthread_cancel':
    /home/user/ClionProjects/producer/wrappers.c:653: undefined reference to `pthread_cancel'
    collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
    make[3]: *** [server] Error 1
    make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/server.dir/all] Error 2
    make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/server.dir/rule] Error 2
    make: *** [server] Error 2
```

wrapper.c includes wrapper.h  which includes pthread.h

I'm overlooking something obvious, but I don't know what.
I tried set, add_library, and install commands but never got output with fewer errors than this.

Edit: Here's the fixed file.

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.6)
project(producer)
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -Wall -g -lpthread")
add_library(wrapper wrapper.h wrapper.c)
add_library(cs537 cs537.h cs537.c)
add_library(request request.h request.c)
add_executable(server server.c)
target_link_libraries(server request wrapper -lpthread)
```

Comment: It's a link error, not a problem finding headers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

thats a linker error, you need to use -pthread in the linker aswell, either directly:

```
target_link_libraries(server -lpthread)
```

or more cross-platform:

```
set(CMAKE_THREAD_PREFER_PTHREAD ON)
find_package (Threads)
target_link_libraries (server ${CMAKE_THREAD_LIBS_INIT})
```